# Quantile residual Q-Q plot in python

Tags: python, scipy, statsmodels

I know how I can get Normal Q-Q plots in Python but how can I get quantile residual Q-Q plots?

I tried to do the three steps written [here](https://www.middleprofessor.com/files/applied-biostatistics_bookdown/_book/generalized-linear-models-i-count-data.html#model-checking-fits-to-count-data) (Chapter 20.2.6.1):

First I tried to adapt [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23819461/4928433) for use with smf.glm (I need to use smf because I have a huge dataframe with hundreds of variables I need to pass):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

# generate some data to check
nobs = 1000
n, p = 50, 0.25
dist0 = stats.nbinom(n, p)
y = dist0.rvs(size=nobs)
x = np.ones(nobs)
df_test = pd.DataFrame({'y': y, 'x': x})

loglike_method = 'nb2'  # or use 'nb2'
#res = sm.NegativeBinomial(y, x, loglike_method=loglike_method).fit(start_params=[0.1, 0.1])
res = smf.glm(formula="y ~ x", data=df_test, family=sm.families.NegativeBinomial()).fit(start_params=[0.1, 0.1])

print(dist0.mean())
print(res.params)

mu = res.predict()   # use this for mean if not constant
mu = mu.mean()
#mu = np.exp(res.params[0])   # shortcut, we just regress on a constant
alpha = res.params[0]

if loglike_method == 'nb1':
    Q = 1
elif loglike_method == 'nb2':    
    Q = 0

size = 1. / alpha * mu**Q
prob = size / (size + mu)

print('data generating parameters'.format(n, p))
print('estimated params'.format(size, prob))

#estimated distribution
dist_est = stats.nbinom(size, prob)
```

But the estimated parameters are totally off.

Next step would be to call stats.nbinom.cdf with those parameters to simulate values ...

Is this the right way?
And how can I get the correct values for size and prob from my fitted model?

Comment: alpha is last parameter in Negbin `alpha = res.params[-1]` see new get_distribution method https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/main/statsmodels/discrete/discrete_model.py#L3742  (will be in next release)

Comment: GLM does not estimate extra parameters. User needs to specify alpha, or default is used.

Comment: @Josef I added alpha=1 but the estimates are still wrong.

Comment: you still have other mistakes in the code. residuals are for each observation. don't use `mu = mu.mean()`. look at the statsmodels code.

Comment: Thank you @Josef I fixed that. But size and prob were still wrong with alpha = 1. I used this function to get alpha: https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/3339#issuecomment-1202908690 And size is now estimated correctly. But I don't get the correct estimation for prob...

Comment: I think mu is wrong with statsmodels formula api. Size is correct because loglike_method  = "nb2" so mu**0 = 1. But prob = size / (size + mu). The statsmodels formula api predict array is also always different. For statsmodels api the predict array is always the same.